# C++ app: How to properly delete/release an allocated object?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory-management, smart-pointers

I am using a GCC compiler on Ubuntu 14.04.
I have a small communication app (not written by me) and I intend to embed it into my own app.
The small comm. app code looks like this:

```
UartComm * commInterface;   
...   
void commInit()   
{   
   commInterface = new UartComm;   
}   

// other functions here that use "commInterface"
// ...

int main()   
{
   commInit();   
   ...   
   if(smthing_1)
      return (-1);  
   if(smthing_2)
      return (-2);  
   ...
   if(smthing_n)
      return (-n);  
   //
   return (0);
}
```

--
As seen above there is no `delete commInterface;` in the original code so, if I embed the above code into my app, rename `main()` to `commFunction()` and call it many times, I will have a lot of memory that is not de-allocated.
The above code is a simplified version. In fact, the code has many exit points/returns. It also has some functions that throw exceptions (I'm not 100% sure they're all catched and handled properly).
So, I guess adding `delete commInterface;` before all `returns` will not be enough in this case...
Hence, my question: Is there a way to properly delete/release `commInterface` in order to embed and use the above module without worrying about memory leaks? Smart pointer maybe or some other idea...?
***Two remarks***:
**1)** I've enabled C++11;
**2)** I' not using (and don't wanna use) *boost*.
Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: I suggest considering smart pointers.

Comment: Is it sensible to have just one `commInterface` that lasts for the entire lifetime of the app? - i.e. make sure you only call `commInit` once.

Comment: Do you really need dynamic allocation?

Comment: I'm curious, what's the reasoning behind the boost allergy? Not that there is any need for boost in this case.

Comment: @user2079303: Not an allergy. But some colleagues suggested exactly what you said: no need for boost...

Comment: @groenhen still, it seems foolish to disallow the use of boost just because you (and I, and your colleagues) assume that it is not needed. If there was a better solution in Boost, wouldn't you want to know of it? I would.

Comment: @user2079303: Yes I would, but finally (after I see all works fine) I'll have to move it to an embedded platform - now it's very difficult to test on that HW. And the idea is that boost package is not available on it.

Comment: @groenhen many Boost features, including the smart pointers it provides, are header only and can be used even if no package is available, or if none would compile on the platform.

Comment: Does the communication app you want to integrate the presence of the global `UartComm * commInterface` variable or could you change this?

Comment: @MikeMB: prefer minimal changes. For the sake of time - I'm in a big rush... But also I'm trying to avoid changing the original code. Experience tells me code that runs ok should be left just like it is. Hope you'll understand my PoV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my hummble opinion this is a scheme that [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) are to be avoided.
Use smart pointers to accomplish [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and in particular [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in the following manner:

```
int commFunction() {
   auto commInterface = std::make_unique<UartComm>(); 
   ...   
   if(smthing_1)
      return (-1);  
   if(smthing_2)
      return (-2);  
   ...
   if(smthing_n)
      return (-n);  
   //
   return (0);
}
```

Mind however that [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is C++14, alternatively for C++11 use the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<UartComm> commInterface(new UartComm);
```

Mind also, that using the suggested scheme a new `UartComm` object is going to be created every time `commFunction` is called. If creation of `UartComm` is an expensive operation or if your design requires reuse of  a single `UartComm` object, you could use the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your `UartComm` object.

Comment: @groenhen if an answer is usefull to you, upvote it ;) this is free !

Comment: Agree, just one remark: When using make_unique, also use auto: `auto commInterface = std::make_unique...`

Comment: @Rene Thnx, adopted.

Comment: @YSC: I always do that, don't worry :) Well 99% of the time. Oh, and I never downvote :)

Comment: @Rene could you explain why please?

Comment: If commFunction is called "*many many times"* I wouldn't recreate and delete the object again every time you call the function - in particular as initialization might involve some costly system calls.

Comment: @YSC It doesn't change anything in the resulting type of the variable. But it's less to type, and in case the type name changes you need to change it in one place only.

Comment: @101010: Ok, tested, it finally works!... I had to modify/adapt it a lilbit, using `reset()` and such, because `commInterface` is also used by other functions inside the module. I can see in my debug/log the destructor is invoked. Great, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to properly delete/release commInterface in order to embed and use the above module without worrying about memory leaks? Smart pointer maybe or some other idea...?

Here is another idea: use a static instance. It will be constructed on first use, and destroyed at the end of the program. This will be faster than dynamic allocation too (though, it doesn't matter much for a single allocation).

```
UartComm& commInterface() {
   static UartComm interface;
   return interface;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `commInterface` is a singleton to be provided to other parts of the application. I suppose further, that you want to make sure that the singleton objet is initialized whenever it shall be used in the application.

Then, I'd suggest to make the variable `static` in order to not expose it to other translation units (which might then access it in an uninitilized state); Instead, provide an accessor function like `UartComm *getCommInterface ()`. Before accessing the variable, check if it is initialized. See code below as an example:

```
static UartComm* commInterface = nullptr;

void commInit()
{
    if (!commInterface)
        commInterface = new UartComm;
}

UartComm *getCommInterface () {
    commInit();
    return commInterface;
}
```

Note that, as you program in C++, you should also think of encapsulating this singleton mechanism in some class; but this is a different topic then.

Comment: An alternative to C-style translation unit static variables are variables embedded in an anonymous namespace.

Comment: + it does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete `commInterface`; that's all!:) Delete it all in the end of
   program.
2. Why do many objects. I was developing application for RS-232
   port (COM-port) and it have 1 object "RS-232" for communication. Or
   you have Ethernet connection?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that a dynamically allocated object must be released.   And that each form of allocation requires the corresponding deallocation.

Although modern operating systems will often clean up for you as the program ends (no need to use operator `delete`), it is a BAD habit to rely on this - not all operating systems make that guarantee.  And operating systems do have bugs.   Furthermore, there is your situation - if you then find you want to rename `main()` to something else to reuse it, you have a problem of a memory leak - your problem would have been easily avoided if you cleaned up in code, rather than relying on cleanup as the program exits.

In your case, the allocation is

```
commInterface = new UartComm;
```

so the corresponding deallocation is

```
delete some_pointer;
```

where `some_pointer` might be `commInterface` (assuming it is visible) or another pointer, of the same type, which stores the same value.

In general terms, there are many other ways to ensure the object is correctly released.   For example;

- Release it in the same function that allocates it.   The problem is that prevents the object from being used after the function returns.
- Return the pointer to the caller, and the caller releases it.

  ```
  UartComm  *commInit()   
  {   
       UartComm *commInterface = new UartComm;   
         // whatever

       return commInterface;
  }   

  int main()
  {
        UartComm *x = commInit();

            // whatever

         delete x;
  }
  ```
- Like the above, but use a smart pointer, so it is not necessary to manually deallocate (the smart pointer does that).

  ```
  std::unique_pointer<UartComm> commInit()   
  {   
       std::unique_pointer<UartComm> commInterface(new UartComm);   

         // whatever

       return commInterface;
  }   

  int main()
  {
        std::unique_pointer<UartComm> x = commInit();

            // whatever

        //   x will be cleaned up as main() returns - no need to release
  }
  ```

There are, of course, numerous other options.   For example, don't use dynamic allocation at all, and simply return an object by value.

Answer (score 1):

If you can remove the global variable I'd go with the singleton solution presented by user2079303 or the local unique_ptr version of 101010. Which one depends on wether you want to recreate the interfaces every time you call your `commFunction()` or not.

**If removing/changing the global variable is not possible** I see two possibilities with minimal code changes (again depending on whether you want to recreate the object or not):

```
UartComm * commInterface = nullptr; //nullptr not necessary but makes it more explicit
...
void commInit()
{
    //only create commInterface the first time commInit() is called
    if( !commInterface )
        commInterface = new UartComm;
}
```

or

```
UartComm * commInterface = nullptr; //nullptr not necessary but makes it more explicit
...
void commInit()
{
    //destruct old UartComm and create new one each time commInit is called
    delete commInterface;
    commInterface = new UartComm;
}
```

Again, those are not solutions I'd recommend in general, but under the previously mentioned constraints they are probably the best you can do.

Also keep in mind that none of these solutions is thread safe (even if UartComm was).